# Spring Boot - KeyCloak directed to 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am new to Keycloak, I am using the official tutorial project on 
https://github.com/sebastienblanc/spring-boot-keycloak-tutorial

for integrating with Springboot application, I have setup the KeyCloak server successfully and the spring boot application also directing to the client application I have created on the Realm I have created on KeyCloak, after providing the correct credentials it directs to the forbidden page.

```
@Controller
class ProductController {

@GetMapping(path = "/products")
public String getProducts(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products", Arrays.asList("iPad","iPhone","iPod"));
    return "products";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    request.logout();
    return "/";
}
}
```

Application.properties file

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=springdemo
keycloak.resource=product-app
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=testuser
keycloak.security-
constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/products/*

server.port=8081
```

I am not getting any error message from KeyCloak console or spring embedded tomcat console.

[Check the tomcat console here - no error](https://pastebin.com/FfFCtaTj)
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a typo at 
`keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=testuser` , you should specify the role here and not the user. 
If you follow the blogpost instructions it should be : 
`keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user`

Comment: I had a 403 as well because my role was uppercased when in fact it should be lowercased as `=user` to match the one specified in the Keycloak server.

Answer (score 3):

In my case here I set `use-resource-role-mappings` to `true`, considering that it would provide both realm and client roles, but it turns out that if this option is set to `true`, *only* client roles are considered.

AFAICS, [there is no way to use both](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-June/002396.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I was using variables separated by dashes, instead of camel case. For example,
I had this (incorrect):

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8083/auth
  realm: springdemo
  resource: Resource_Name
  public-client: true
  security-constraints[0].auth-roles[0]: user
  security-constraints[0].security-collections[0].patterns[0]: /
```

instead of (correct):

```
keycloak:
  authServerUrl: http://localhost:8083/auth
  realm: springdemo
  resource: Resource_Name
  publicClient: true
  securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]: user
  securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this Week End to replay the example from the very interesting DEvoxx Sebastien speak.

I had the same 403 error with the role "user" specified in the property
`keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user`

The "user" role does not exists in the default keycloak configuration. You have to create it before in your realm  (realm/configuration/roles) and assign it to your user (realm/users/user/roles mappings).

Answer (score 0):

About that tutorial, I just have a problem with logout feature.

Sometimes the logout does not work.

1) I click on logout and then I click on /products, then I am not redirected to keycloak login page

2) If I click on logout, then I refresh the browser page, then I click on /products I am redirected to the keycloak login page.

It seams to be that the logout implementation from HttpServletRequest is not enough to really logout the user ?

`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException{
        request.logout();
        return "/";
}
```

`

If somebody has an explanation on that behavior between springboot and keycloak. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I also had the same issue, several times.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this might help someone.

In my case, I had resource authorization enabled (so client was not public). I had to do the following

Under Client
Authorization -> Settings -> Policy Enforcement Mode

Set it to "Permissive"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to turn off Client Authentication and Authorization (both) in client config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).