# !role error in keycloak while accessing a resource

Tags: java, rest, keycloak

I have secured my rest api with Keycloak. After authentication, when I try to access rest API , I get:

> 403 error. Unable to access rest api. Reason !role.

In configuration I have specified role as *:

```
    ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
    context.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
    securityHandler.addRole("*");
    ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/*");
    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();

    constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"*"});
```

Was my assumption of specifying any role by using **'*'**  wrong or does the error mean something different?

I see following logs in JettyKeycloakAuthentciator logs:

> 2018-05-24 12:55:52,253 [DEBUG]
>   [ers.PreAuthActionsHandler(handleRequest  )] - adminRequest
>   http://localhost:7100/api/v1/design/test 2018-05-24 12:55:52,254
>   [DEBUG] [TokenRequestAuthenticator(thenticateToken)] - Verifying
>   access_token 2018-05-24 12:55:52,255 [DEBUG]
>   [TokenRequestAuthenticator(thenticateToken)] - successful authorized
>   2018-05-24 12:55:52,255 [DEBUG]
>   [JettyRequestAuthenticator(rAuthentication)] - Completing bearer
>   authentication. Bearer roles: [uma_authorization] 2018-05-24
>   12:55:52,255 [DEBUG] [ters.RequestAuthenticator(eAuthentication)] -
>   User '8f9381df-2f7e-4ff8-9ef5-2123b03db3c9' invoking
>   'http://localhost:7100/api/v1/design/test' on client 'my_server'
>   2018-05-24 12:55:52,255 [DEBUG]
>   [ters.RequestAuthenticator(authenticate   )] - Bearer AUTHENTICATED
>   2018-05-24 12:55:52,255 [DEBUG]
>   [thenticatedActionsHandler(handledRequest )] -
>   AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke
>   http://localhost:7100/api/v1/design/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the correct way to set any role is:

```
constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"**"});
```

i.e. **double *** and not **single ***

Also, I removed this line:

```
securityHandler.addRole("*");
```